# SQL insert one record with multiple relational data in one transaction

Tags: mysql, sql

Say, I have a customer profile with many contacts. That means I will have separated contact table from customer table.

**tbl_customer**

```
  CustomerId (PK, NOT NULL, UNIQUE, AUTO_INCREMENT)
  CustomerName
  Address
  (etc)
```

**tbl_contact**

```
 ContactId (PK, NOT NULL, UNIQUE, AUTO_INCREMENT)
  CustomerId (FK REFERENCES tbl_customer(CustomerId), CONSTRAINT)
  Contact Type
  Contact Number
```

So now let say, a customer called `John Leweinsky` has 4 contacts.

```
ContactType1: Fax
ContactType2: Office Phone
ContactType3: Personal Phone
ContactType4: Personal Phone
```

Can this be done in one query transaction without knowing `CustomerId`?

Thanks for advance if you have answered this.

Comment: What are you inserting if you do not know the CustomerID?

Comment: That's the question, I am not sure if I am thinking legit. But waiting for someone to prove out :)

Comment: `CustomerName` is unique or not

Comment: CustomerName is not unique

Comment: do you want to insert `tbl_customer` and `tbl_contact` in same time ah?

Comment: What is your backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
START TRANSACTION;

insert into (feilds name) values(Values);

insert into tbl_contact(CustomerId ,ContactType,ContacNumber) 
values((select max(CustomerId) from tbl_customer),'type1','Fax');

COMMIT;
```

Pass all other contacttype

Comment: then my transaction has to be locked when it is commiting?

Comment: What will you do to change the table design if you have one customer to multi contacts without putting the customer name in unique.

Comment: saving data is store procedure and using same concept. save first table. then getting max id after that store second table @lannyboy

Comment: I mean is there way to tweak this design instead of this traditional commit?

Comment: in my office this process is going on then only i suggest you. use store procedure with roll back option if any exception occur the transaction is roll back otherwise its commit

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the name is unique, you can do this as:

```
insert into tbl_contact(CustomerId, ContactType, ContactNumber)
    select cust.CustomerId, c.ContactType, c.ContactNumber
    from (select 'Fax' as ContactType, Faxnumber as ContactNumber union all
          select 'Office', Officenumber union all
          select 'PersonalPhone', PersonalPhone union all
          select 'PersonalPhone', PersonalPhone
         ) c cross join
         Customers cust
    where cust.CustomerName = 'John Leweinsky';
```

If name is not unique, you need some way to disambiguate the customers.

Comment: I guess no way I could just do it without knowing the CustomerID right?

Comment: @lannyboy . . . Not if you are storing the `CustomerId` in the contacts table.  There are sometimes other options depending on the database, such as insertable views with triggers.

Comment: Well, like I said in the previous post: For example in my company there are 3 people called "Rob Martin". And with the query above will be ambiguous :)

Answer (score 0):

No, the only way to properly add something to tbl_contact is with the CustomerId. You're Customer Name is not unique ( nor should it be ) so you have no way to link your contacts with John Leweinsky, unless this is just a toy example and you want to pretend that John Leweinsky is unique.

You can add the contacts without knowing the CustomerId ( in some database engines, PostgreSQL for exapmle ) but the won't be connected to John Leweinsky.

Comment: Well, in my company there are 3 people called "Rob Martin". And with the query above will be ambiguous :)